# Solution verification for a determinant computation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

## Probem

Suppose $\alpha \neq \beta $. Evaluate

$$D_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
  x_1 & \alpha & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha \\
\beta &  x_2 & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha \\
\beta & \beta & x_3 &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &        &\vdots &\vdots \\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & x_{n-1} &\alpha \\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &x_n \\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

## Solution

Notice that
\begin{eqnarray*}
D_n&&=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & \alpha & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\beta & x_2 & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\beta & \beta & x_3 &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & x_{n-1} &\alpha\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &x_n\\
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & \alpha & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha+0\\
\beta & x_2 & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha+0\\
\beta & \beta & x_3 &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha+0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & x_{n-1} &\alpha+0\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &\alpha+(x_n-\alpha)\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&&=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & \alpha & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\beta & x_2 & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\beta & \beta & x_3 &\cdots & \alpha &\alpha\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & x_{n-1} &\alpha\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &\alpha\\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & \alpha & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &0\\
\beta & x_2 & \alpha &\cdots & \alpha &0\\
\beta & \beta & x_3 &\cdots & \alpha &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & x_{n-1} &0\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &x_n-\alpha\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&&=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1-\beta & \alpha-\beta & \alpha-\beta &\cdots & \alpha-\beta &0\\
0 & x_2-\beta & \alpha-\beta &\cdots & \alpha-\beta &0\\
0  & 0 & x_3-\alpha &\cdots &\alpha-\beta &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots & x_{n-1}-\beta &0\\
\beta & \beta &\beta&\cdots & \beta &\alpha\\
\end{vmatrix}+(x_n-\alpha)D_{n-1}\\
&&=\alpha \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i-\beta)+(x_n-\alpha)D_{n-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Likewise，one can obtain
$$D_n=\beta \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i-\alpha)+(x_n-\beta)D_{n-1}.$$
Since $\alpha \neq \beta$，it follows that
$$D_n=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}\left[\alpha \prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\beta)-\beta \prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\alpha)\right].$$

Comment: Looks good, I think!